# Linq2db for SQLite - Xamarin form

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, linq2db

When connect to SQLite always got this exception

> {System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'LinqToDB.Data.DataConnection' threw an exception. 
>   ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'LinqToDB.DataProvider.SqlServer.SqlServerTools:_commandBuilder' 
>   (0) due to: Could not resolve type with token 010000fe from typeref (expected class 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder' 
>   in assembly '

[image: this is nugget version]

```
IDataProvider dataProvider = new LinqToDB.DataProvider.SQLite.SQLiteDataProvider();

            ConnectionStringSettings connectionString = new ConnectionStringSettings
            {
                Name = "Database",
                ProviderName = "SQLite",
                ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + path 
            };

            using (var db = new DataConnection(dataProvider, connectionString.ConnectionString))
            {
                var it = db.Query<ITEM>("SELECT * FROM ITEMS");
            }
```

Comment: Sorry about that - it is linq2db 2.6-2.6.1 regression for xamarin. You need to use pre-2.6 version for now

Comment: @DLuk It works now. Thank you so much.